# Can you only perform arithmetic in registers when programming in atmel studios?

Tags: assembly, atmel

I need to multiply two 4 byte numbers. I can store those values in the x,y,z registers but then how do I multiply them since I can only multiply 8x8 bits at a time? I know how to allocate memory in dseg but arithmetic functions can't be performed there.
 The devices I'm using for simulation are 169p and the 2560. Mul may be used.

I have tried using the x,y,z registers but I can't figure how to take care of the carries and such. I know that they can be found in registers 0,1 and so fourth. I tried to allot memory locations large enough to store the numbers for arithmetic but I would have to move them to registers for operations anyway.

Comment: Thank you jester for your reply jester. I may be coming to a solution soon

Answer (score 0):

You can implement any of the well-known multiplication algorithms for yourself, or, if you insist on building on top of the existing 8 bit multiply you can use some elementary algebra. Example for 16 bit case, with s=2^8:

```
op1 = a*s + b
op2 = c*s + d
op1 * op2 = (a*s + b) * (c*s + d) = a*c*s*s + b*c*s + a*d*s + b*d
```

All the variable multiplications here are 8 bit with 16 bit result. Add the partial terms into the final result shifted appropriately based on the power of `s`.

For 32 bit, this will be a little more complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finished my problem of multiplying $A3B4 and $421C using Atmel AVR. Here is the code for anyone that's looking for an example of this. The final answer is stored at data locations 0x2000-0x2003

```
ldi yl,0xB4
 ldi yh,0xA3
 ldi zl,0x1c
 ldi zh,0x42

 mul zl,yl

 mov r15,r0
 mov r16,r1

 mul zl,yh

 mov r17,r0
 mov r18,r1

 mul zh,yl

 mov r19,r0
 mov r20,r1

 mul zh, yh

 mov r21,r0
 mov r22,r1

 adc r16,r17
 adc r16,r19
 adc r18,r20
 adc r18,r21

 ldi r25,0
 adc r22,r25

 ldi yl,0x00
 ldi yh,0x20

 std y+0,r22
 std y+1,r18
 std y+2, r16
 std y+3, r15
```